Is this a good way to handle bad statements？
I can't handle wrong statements very well now. Once an error occurs in the previous statement, my subsequent statements will not be parsed correctly.
I added an error statement branch：
root
: sqlStatements? (MINUS MINUS)? EOF
;
sqlStatements
: (sqlStatement (MINUS MINUS)? SEMI?
| emptyStatement
| errorStatement
)
(sqlStatement (MINUS MINUS)? SEMI?
| emptyStatement
| errorStatement
)
;

errorStatement
: erroneous=.+? SEMI
{notifyErrorListeners("error statement: " + $erroneous.text);}
;

But I don't know if this is a good implementation

There's no need to create your custom error handling. If certain input doesn't match you will get an error from ANTLR4, which you can handle in a way that makes sense to you. Keep in mind there are not only unknown statement errors (known as no viable alt errors), but also missing or extraneous input etc.

If I don't do this, I don't know how to handle errors better, because if I find that the previous statement is incorrect, the following statements cannot be parsed correctly.My main purpose is to divide a batch of SQL statements one by one

These are 2 different aspects: (1) error handling should be done with an error listener, (2) statement splitting is a task on its own. Using a parser for that is way to slow. Instead use something like this splitting function.

I have tried this method before, but some Sql is quite complex, such as the creation of procedure, which do not end with a semicolon.
